# Oracle built-in datatypes system view

Tags: sql, oracle, database-administration

Folks!

Does somebody know an Oracle **built-in datatypes system dictionary view**?

Example:

```
SELECT DUMP ('HASAN') FROM DUAL;
```

returns

```
Typ=96 Len=5: 72,65,83,65,78
```

Oracle documentation says that it is CHAR or NCHAR datatype.

But is there a view, where I can find this datatype by code returned (Typ=96)?

Does it exist at all?

Comment: see `object_id` and `data_object_id` in `dba_objects` table. String literals should be `char` by default unless you change nls_settings.

Comment: Unfortunately, there weren't any type with object_id or data_object_id of 96 :(

Comment: I don't believe that exists in the data dictionary. You could build your own look-up table I suppose, starting [from the documented types](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements001.htm#SQLRF30020), but that list isn't complete. There are other date types for instance; dump `sysdate` to see one that isn't in the docs. (There are a few more [here](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNOCI/oci03typ.htm#GUID-7DA48B90-07C7-41A7-BC57-D8F358A4EEBE__CEGGBDFC) and [here](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNOCI/oci03typ.htm#GUID-D69455D9-CE01-44CC-B5A9-E541C7774805__CEGIEEJI).)

Comment: `SELECT t.typecode, name
  FROM sys.type$ t, sys.obj$ o
  AND t.toid = o.oid$ and t.typecode = 96;`

Comment: @fg78nc - I stand corrected *8-) Nice. Just an observation though, that it doesn't show NCHAR or NVARCHAR2..

Comment: @AlexPoole No, it does not, even in Oracle docs it is same code for `nchar` and `char`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
  SELECT t.typecode, name
  FROM sys.type$ t, sys.obj$ o
  WHERE t.toid = o.oid$ and t.typecode = 96;
```

Comment: Exactly! Thanks a lot!

Comment: @HasanAlizada Buyur

Answer (score 3):

You can also check source code of DBMS_TYPES package

```
select TEXT 
from dba_source 
where name = 'DBMS_TYPES' 
    and regexp_like(text, 'TYPECODE');


TYPECODE_DATE            PLS_INTEGER :=  12;
TYPECODE_NUMBER          PLS_INTEGER :=   2;
TYPECODE_RAW             PLS_INTEGER :=  95;
TYPECODE_CHAR            PLS_INTEGER :=  96;
TYPECODE_VARCHAR2        PLS_INTEGER :=   9;
TYPECODE_VARCHAR         PLS_INTEGER :=   1;
TYPECODE_MLSLABEL        PLS_INTEGER := 105;
TYPECODE_BLOB            PLS_INTEGER := 113;
TYPECODE_BFILE           PLS_INTEGER := 114;
TYPECODE_CLOB            PLS_INTEGER := 112;
TYPECODE_CFILE           PLS_INTEGER := 115;
TYPECODE_TIMESTAMP       PLS_INTEGER := 187;
TYPECODE_TIMESTAMP_TZ    PLS_INTEGER := 188;
TYPECODE_TIMESTAMP_LTZ   PLS_INTEGER := 232;
TYPECODE_INTERVAL_YM     PLS_INTEGER := 189;
TYPECODE_INTERVAL_DS     PLS_INTEGER := 190;
TYPECODE_REF             PLS_INTEGER := 110;
TYPECODE_OBJECT          PLS_INTEGER := 108;
TYPECODE_VARRAY          PLS_INTEGER := 247;            /* COLLECTION TYPE */
TYPECODE_TABLE           PLS_INTEGER := 248;            /* COLLECTION TYPE */
TYPECODE_NAMEDCOLLECTION PLS_INTEGER := 122;
TYPECODE_OPAQUE          PLS_INTEGER := 58;                 /* OPAQUE TYPE */
TYPECODE_NCHAR           PLS_INTEGER := 286;
TYPECODE_NVARCHAR2       PLS_INTEGER := 287;
TYPECODE_NCLOB           PLS_INTEGER := 288;
TYPECODE_BFLOAT          PLS_INTEGER := 100;
TYPECODE_BDOUBLE         PLS_INTEGER := 101;
TYPECODE_UROWID          PLS_INTEGER := 104;
```

Note, numbers in DBMS_TYPES are related to PL/SQL. However, `DUMP` is a SQL function which you cannot use in PL/SQL. Thus these numbers are slightly different.

Answer (score 1):

There's DBA_TYPEs, which has a predefined column, e.g.:

```
SELECT * FROM dba_types WHERE predefined = 'YES';
```

That seems to have a few of the obvious types (e.g. NUMBER, VARCHAR2, etc) in it, but I wouldn't like to say that's exclusive (for example, the ANYDATA datatype has predefined = NO).

Anyway, it ought to give you an idea of where to look, although why you'd want to I'm not sure?

N.B. If you want to see a list of the dictionary tables, you can do:

```
select * from dictionary;
```

You can filter as appropriate, if you can't remember the exact table name!

Comment: Already filtered. Nothing related to this issue has been found. Seems, this is only-documented. No view does exists for it.

Comment: @HasanAlizada Check my answer, it does return required info.

Comment: Just found out, that dba_types does *NOT* contain NCHAR or NVARCHAR2. The function dump lists them as type CHAR or VARCHAR2. This whole type system seems to be an assembly of hacks, accumulated during the years :-(